# JUnit Testing a class

Tags: java, junit

This is the first time I've had to write a J Unit Test and I'm stuck on how to even start. This class represents a single cell on a Othello board it has a grid and token value.

I wanted to test the constructor with both "black" and "white" and different locations, and I also wanted to test all of the setters and getters.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
public class BoardCell
{
    /**
     * The Item at this BoardCell.
     */
    private Item token;

    /**
     * The CellLocation of this BoardCell.
     */
    private BoardLocation location;

    /**
     * Constructor.
     * @param row the row number.
     * @param col the column number.
     * @param token the Item value.
     */
    public BoardCell(int row, int col, Item token)
    {
        this.token = token;
        location = new BoardLocation(row, col);
    }

    /**
     * Sets the Item value.
     * @param token the Item value.
     */
    public void setItem(Item token)
    {
        this.token = token;
    }

    /**
     * Set the value of the Item in this BoardCell.
     * @param val the value of the Item.
     */
    public void setValue(String val)
    {
        this.token.setValue(val);
    }

    /**
     * Gets the Item value.
     * @return the Item at this BoardCell.
     */
    public Item getItem()
    {
        return token;
    }

    /**
     * Get the BoardLocation for this BoardCell.
     * @return the BoardLocation for this BoardCell.
     */
    public BoardLocation getLocation()
    {
        return location;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using IntelliJ? If so, try highlighting BoardCell and hold down Shift-Ctrl-T. It will build a test for you.

Answer (score 4):

You need to start by creating a new class that will hold all your different tests, you can call it, say, `BoardCellTest` or `BoardCellTestCase`.

In this class, you'll need to add your different test cases, which are `public void` methods annotated with `@Test`.

Each method should then assert (with the methods in the `Assert` class) what you need to test, by creating the right `BoardCell` objects and getting their values, or setting new ones.

Answer (score 2):

It would be best to start with the information on the [junit site](http://junit.org/) and some tutorials.  Additionally, a best practice is to write the test first, and then the function it is testing.  That said, here's a general outline:

1)  Come up with a list of tests you want.  Focus on each function and the different ways it can be used (and ways it can go wrong).

2)  Write tests that compare expected behavior to actual behavior, something like this:

```
    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        // In this function you'll want to create instances of the class that you will then test
    }

    @Test
    public void testSomething() {
    assertEquals(BoardCell.getItem(), whatever you think it should equal); //or whatever you're testing
    }

    @Test
    public void etcetera() . . .
```

Comment: Why not use assertEquals? It provides nicer output when the objects do not equal (assuming you override the `toString` method)

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for code coverage or simply to see if a method works the way you intended it to? If you're simply looking for coverage then simply create a class and annotate methods with `@Test`, most coverage tools will pick up JUnit/Surefire reports and interpret them appropriately.

If you wish to test something like a getter or setter works then you can use a simple assertion test.

```java
@Test
public void testGetItem() throws Exception {
    Item item = new BlackItem();
    BoardCell cell = new BoardCell(128, 256, item);
    assertNotNull("item should not be null", cell.getItem());
    assertEquals("items should be considered equal", item, cell.getItem());
}
```

If you override `toString` in a class then JUnit will handily print out the result of `toString` if the assertion fails, this is true for `assertEquals`, `assertArrayEquals` (I believe) and `assertThat`. I don't have an exact copy of the exception to hand but it will be something along the lines of this:

```java
org.junit.AssertionError: Expected Item{name="Black Item"} but was Item{name="White Item"}
Expected: Item{name="Black Item"}
Actual: Item{name="White Item"}
```

Something that may come in handy for testing equality of `BoardLocation` and `Item` objects. A good place to read up more on assertions would be the JUnit site as mentioned by other poster and their [GitHub wiki](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Assertions) which I personally  prefer.